# Exponential function is injective

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would we show that the exponential function, $a^x$, $a \in \mathbb{R}^+-\{1\}$ is injective? I want to not use the inverse log function as originally I was trying to come up with algebraic justification of why the log function is well-defined and it looks like I can show that assuming the exponential function $a^x$ is injective. It looks like showing the function is injective is equivalent to showing that $a^x=1$ implies $x=0$. Now I am trying to figure out some kind of contradiction if $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess that your definition of $\exp$ involves the ODE
$$
y' = ay, y(0) = 1\to y(t) = \exp_a t
$$(this is not $t\to a^t$, but $a$ does not really matter here).

Let us assume that $y(x)=1, x>1$ ($x<1$ is similar), and assume that for $t\in[0,x], y(t)\neq 1$.

Then $y$ must be decreasing either near $0$  or near $x$. It is impossible because both derivatives are $=a$.

Then you are done, because $$
\exp :\Bbb R-\{0\},+\to\Bbb R,\times
$$is a group homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

So you're actually trying to prove that $f(x) = log_a(x)$, where $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, is injective (i.e. one-to-one).  Injective (and surjective) proofs are generally difficult (you usually prove them by assuming something is injective).  For instance, let's try to prove by contradiction.  Assume there are two values of $x$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = \log_a(x_1) = \log_a(x_2)$ and $x_1 \neq x_2$.  All we need to do is show that $x_1 = x_2$ to prove the contradiction (and thus that $f(x)$ is injective).

\begin{align*}
\log_a(x_1) =& \log_a(x_2) \rightarrow a^{\log_a(x_1)} = a^{\log_a(x_2)} \\
x_1 =& x_2 \text{, q.e.d.}
\end{align*}

This is the definition of the logarithm (as the inverse of the exponential).  Now, it's worth pointing out that this is not totally correct if we allow complex numbers.  If we allow complex numbers, then we can write:

\begin{align*}
\log_a(x) = y = y_R + y_Ii \text{, where } a,x,y_R,\text{ and } y_I \text{ are real numbers}
\end{align*}

We need to solve the following equation to find $y$:

\begin{align*}
a^y = x \rightarrow \left(e^{\ln(a)}\right)^{y_R + y_Ii} = e^{\ln(a)(y_R + y_Ii)} = xe^{2\pi n i}
\end{align*}

This leads to two equations:

\begin{align*}
e^{\ln(a)y_R} = x \rightarrow y_R = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(a)} \\
\ln(a)y_I = 2\pi n \rightarrow y_I = \frac{2\pi n}{\ln(a)} \\
y(n) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(a)} + \frac{2\pi n}{\ln(a)}i
\end{align*}

What this means is that, in general, this function is *not* injective, but if we assume it maps from $\mathbb{R}^+ \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, then there is only a single value of $n$ ($n = 0$) such that this equation is equal (with a real value of $y$).  This means that for each (positive) real value of $x$ there is a single real value, $y$, such that the equation (or function) holds--this makes the function injective.